# Can mooshrooms breed with cows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that you can breed mooshrooms with other mooshrooms, but can you breed them with cows? If so, what will it produce?

Comment: I am guessing the down votes are because the answer is easily obtainable.  I copied/pasted your question into google and the very first page returned is the page Timmy Jim links to in his answer.

Comment: I guess that's what I get

Comment: Don't be disheartened. I have had the same issue, even lately SE has been my go-to place for any questions I have. I just have to remember to do my homework *first*, before I ask the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Snapshot 12w07a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_12w07a#Fixes) removed the ability for mooshroms to breed with cows.

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mooshroom#Breeding), mooshrooms can only breed with other mooshrooms.  If you shear the mooshroom, it becomes a regular cow again, to which it can then breed with other cows once again:

> **A mooshroom cannot be bred with a cow**, unless the mooshroom has been sheared.